# WPF ControlTemplate TargetType match

Tags: wpf

I have a component that is derived from a ComboBox. In it, I created a dependency property "myDependencyProp" as the following code. However, in XAML, when I refer to this property, VS says the type is not available in ComboBox and don't run the application. When I set the ControlTemplate TargetType to my:myComboBox, it works correctly, however, VS displays a warning: "myComboBox ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type ComboBox". The application runs correctly, but I don't like this warning. How can I fix it? Thanks! (Obs: my: is just a ficticious alias to myNameSpaces).

C#:

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    public partial class myComboBox : ComboBox
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty myDependencyPropProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("myDependencyProp", typeof(bool),
            typeof(myComboBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public myComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool IsFirstItemTip
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(myDependencyPropProperty); }
            set { SetValue(myDependencyPropProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:myComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                           ...
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <ContentPresenter
                           ...
                        </ContentPresenter>

                        <Popup 
                           ...
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                                <Condition Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>

                                <Condition Property="myDependencyProp" Value="True"/>

                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter ... />
                            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: I guess you should also set the `TargetType` of the `Style` to `"{x:Type my:myComboBox}"`.

Answer (score 1):

change this line
`<Style x:Key="myComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">` to `<Style x:Key="myComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type my:myComboBox}">` to get rid of the warning. The warning is telling you that your style will implicitly get applied to all `ComboBoxes` but the control template is intended for those types which are derived from `myComboBox`

Comment: I made that change, the application still runs, but now the warning message is: "myComboBox TargetType does not matches type of element ComboBox".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but I solved the problem by doing the following:

First, I returned all TargetTypes to {x: Type ComboBox}, then all warnings are gone.

After, instead of using the MultiTrigger as previously presented, I used MultiDataTrigger, as the code below:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=myDependencyProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter .../>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

That is it!

Comment: This is just a hack (or workaround). The binding `Path` is not resolved at design time (so no warning) but at runtime it runs OK.

Comment: Yes, I know, but all previous suggestions didn't resolve those warnings. I can not see, for now, another solution.